# Deliver encrypted data and decrypt it client side

Tags: encryption

I'm working on a project with some sensitive data. I'm trying to do statistics about Facebook conversation with a client only website. Until now, I have a big JSON file of a Facebook conversation that I parse and do stuff with data. I want to be able to deliver this file only to my friends. So, what I thought is that I locally encrypt it (with I don't know yet which algo), deliver the encrypted file and give the password to my friend so only them can decrypt it. Do you think it will work and it will be secure enought ? I don't want someone to be able to bruteforce it or whatever, as it is private conversation. And do you have any recommendation about the algo I should use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed an abstract question so you may get only an abstract answer

> deliver the encrypted file and give the password to my friend so only them can decrypt it. Do you think it will work and it will be secure enought ?

There are a few conditions to make encryption safe.

- using any modern cipher which is not considered weak (e.g. AES-128 provides enough of security)
- the encryption key is random (or password used to generate the key is long and random enough)
- optionally you may add an authentication tag to ensure message integrity

  > And do you have any recommendation about the algo I should use ?

To encrypt data itself, any current modern cipher will do, e. g. aes, 3des,...

If you don't want to dive into security and you just want to encrypt a file, you can you some out of box  tools which would do that for you. Try to look at openssl, pgp, gpg or nppcrypt (plugin for notepad++). Just make the password long and random.

The question is how do you get the key or password to your friend safely. You can either use different channel or using asynchronous  (such as RSA or ECC). You can search, read, try out and ask more specific question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that means that, if the key is strong enough, I don't have to be afraid of someone trying to bruteforce the file ? I have to be sure about that, as I don't have any server, there is no login available and the conversation file is delivered statically